# PHP json encode foreach only loops through the first item

Tags: php, json

So I'm busy at creating a system.
That system generates a bit of JSON

For example:

```
{
    "Builds": [
        {
            "title": "test",
            "item1": "3",
            "item2": "3",
            "item3": "0",
            "item4": "0",
            "item5": "0",
            "item6": "0"
        },
        {
            "title": "test2",
            "item1": "3",
            "item2": "3",
            "item3": "2",
            "item4": "0",
            "item5": "0",
            "item6": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now im trying to get every "build" with a foreach in PHP this only loops the first time and then does nothing.

```
$i = 0;

foreach($builds as $build){
    //echo $i;
    echo $build[$i]['title'];
    echo '<img src="' . $build[$i]['item1'] . '" alt=""></img>';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a counter? Get rid of it. `echo $build['title'];` etc

Comment: @JohnConde 
The json file makes me using the counter. 
Unless im going with another JSON structure.

But thats still not an answer to my question, about how to solve it.

Cuase i think it is strange it only loops one time..

Comment: should be `foreach($builds['Builds'] as $build){`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the for loop, you don't need a counter.

```
$json = '{"Builds":[{"title":"test","item1": "3","item2": "3","item3": "0","item4": "0","item5": "0","item6": "0"},{"title":"test2","item1": "3","item2": "3","item3": "2","item4": "0","item5": "0","item6": "0"}]}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$builds = $data['Builds'];
foreach($builds as $build){
    echo $build['title'];
    echo '<img src="' . $build['item1'] . '" alt=""></img>';
}
```

The only reason for a counter would be, if you want to iterate over the item elements in your builds.

```
for ($i = 1; isset($build['item' . $i]); $i++) {
    echo '<img src="' . $build['item' . $i] . '" alt=""></img>';
}
```

Comment: If i do it without the coutner it still doesnt work.
I am getting an undefinded index error.

Comment: Probably want `foreach($builds['Builds']`

Comment: If you get an undefined index error, your $build var doesn't contain the content of the json you posted - if you tried my code, you would see, that it actually worked

Comment: Does it? `$build['item1']` is an object: `$build->item1`, `$build->title` and `$data->Builds`

Comment: @HasseBjörk json_decode as second param, which indicates that the return value is an assoc array

Comment: @Philipp thanks i got your version working! Awesome i forgot the  $data['buils'] part i dont completely get why i have to do it but well thanks!

Comment: @Philipp `true` I missed that one! Thank you!

Comment: @CodeGodie Why should I use anonym objects? There are many good reasons for arrays: json_decode to an array is faster; Using arrays might be easier; There are already many functions for array manipulations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're working with an array of objects. This is how you should be doing it:

```
<?php

$json = ""; //your JSON string
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach ($obj->Builds as $build) {
    echo $build->title;
    echo "<img src='$build->item1' alt=''>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Im using json_decode($build,true) which only returns arrays:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version

```
$builds = '{"Builds":[{"title":"test","item1": "3","item2": "3","item3": "0","item4": "0","item5": "0","item6": "0"},{"title":"test2","item1": "3","item2": "3","item3": "2","item4": "0","item5": "0","item6": "0"}]}';

foreach(json_decode( $builds )->Builds as $build ){
    echo $build->title;
    echo '<img src="' . $build->item1 . '" alt=""></img>';
}
```

First you need to use the json decoded object `Builds` to iterate through. This will give you objects to display, like `$build->title`

Comment: They arent objects though cause i use json_decode($builds,true)

only arrays are given back as return value

Comment: I did not see that in your example... Well, this does work!